# how to grab data if value = yes

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

So I have a worksheet that has 2 columns

```
column A(name)    Column B(Yes/No)    Column c
Name1)            YES                 Name1
Name2             NO                  Name3
Name3             YES                 Name5
Name4             NO
Name5             YES
```

How can i then grab the data from based on the yes / no value using a formula so that it shows in Column c and leaves out the no values

I know it should be on the lines of
=if(B2="Yes")then ref A2 but put in column c

but i know this is wrong, any pointers?

Comment: Why do you think it has 2 columns? Also why if B2=yes does it reference A1

Comment: yeah, sorry, been a long day. need to formulate if b2 = yes then ref a1 but put it in a c2 downwards, missing any no values

Comment: Simple solution: use a filter and select YES.  That will hide all of the non-YES rows.  If you need a consolidated list, copy the filtered names and paste.  The pasted version won't have any hidden rows.

Comment: Do you mean `=IF(B2="Yes",A2,"")`

Comment: Yeah i kind of went down the filter option, makes it easier.

Comment: You should really let @fixer1234 answer this if it's right (which based upon your answer, it is).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[image]

**How it works:**

- Write **Yes** in cell C1.
- Enter this array formula in cell C2, finish with Ctrl+Shift+Enter &
  Fill down.

.

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$6, SMALL(IF($C$1=$B$2:$B$6, ROW($B$2:$B$6)-MIN(ROW($B$2:$B$6))+1, ""), ROW(A1))),"")}
```

Comment: What is wrong with this answer, Y it has downvoted? Since I've shown a better & intelligent formula will help the OP & others too !!